# Symbol for the relation of divisibility

Tags: symbols

How to write '$a$ is divisible by $b$' in a Latex formula? The symbol \vdots does not look satisfactory.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually `\mid` is employed (a solid line), but the problem of denoting the symbol with three dots was already dealt with on the site.

Comment: @egreg: Many thanks. A question still remains: I want a formula of the type $\sum\limits_{k\vdots n}$, that is, the symbol must be very small.

Comment: I added the code in my answer to the linked thread

Comment: You're welcome! Don't worry for the duplicate: it happens quite often; I remembered to have already seen something like that, so I could be able to form a suitable keyword for a lookup. Welcome again to the site: we're waiting for other contributions; consider registering for being able to fully participate.